# Copy to clipboard not working in IE 11

Tags: jquery, copy, clipboard, zeroclipboard

For copy text to clipboard in MVC I have use ZeroClipboard.swf and jquery.zclip.js

```
<script>
    $("#buttonCopyLink").zclip({
        path: "/Content/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy: function () {
            return $('input#copyLinkText').val();
        }
    });
</script>
```

This working without any issue in all browsers but not in IE 11.
Please provide any solution to fix this issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your version of Flash.  I had the same problem - worked for me in Chrome but failed in IE11.  I went to this site:

http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/

And saw in Chrome I was running v14 but in IE11:

You have version 11,4,402,287 installed

After upgrading Flash in IE11, that page reported:

You have version 14,0,0,145 installed

And zeroclipboard then worked for me.  I was able to verify on its demo page: http://zeroclipboard.org.